# How to compare two strings if they are not equal

Tags: objective-c

How would I compare two strings if they are not equal?

Answer (score 47):

Just use isEqualToString and put an ! before the whole expression, like so:

```
if (![self.passwordField.text isEqualToString: self.confirmPasswordField.text])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the NSString compare method (or one of the more detailed variations)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414082-compare

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410893-compare